# Graphing a Double Absolute Value Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, absolute-value

How would I graph the function $y=|(|x|-1)|$ in a piecewise manner?

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking. Are you asking how to graph the function $y=|(|x|-1)|$?

Comment: yes exactly that

Comment: Well, you can do the outside piecewise function first ($y$ is either $|x|-1$ or $-(|x|-1)=1-|x|$, and then take the inner absolute value piecewise. You’ll have nested piecewise functions, but you can pull those apart if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the abs function is a piecewise function so you only have to consider cases.

Case 1:
$|x| - 1 > 0$ then $|x|>1$ so either $x>1$ or $x≤-1$ which give you the equations $y = x-1$, and $y = -x-1$

Case 2:
$|x| - 1 ≤ 0$ then $|x|≤1$ so $x≤1$ and $x≥-1$ which give you the equations $y = 1-x$, and $y = x+1$

So, your final answer is
$$y =
\begin{cases}
-x-1,  & \text{if $x≤-1$} \\
x+1, & \text{if $-1<x≤0$} \\
1-x, & \text{if $0<x≤1$} \\
x-1, & \text{if $1<x$}
\end{cases}$$

Considering the abs function is continuous, a simple check of equivalence at endpoints shows a reasonable confidence of correctness.

Comment: I don't understand why two different cases were used and how you knew when it was supposed to be >= or only > .